# how to disable scroll lock only in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using an led keyboard so the keyboard led light is on by activating the scroll lock key. Is there a solution I want to disable scroll lock only in excel so that the scroll lock key remains active on the keyboard?.

Note : I use excel 2010 64 bit

thanks
jack

Comment: @braX , I don't know the solution used yet so I asked in this post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main effect of [Scroll Lock](https://www.excel-easy.com/examples/scroll-lock.html) being active is that the selected cell won't change when you press an arrow key (the pane will scroll instead).

So, I guess you could force Excel to update your selection based on the keys you press. Here's a proof of concept of how to do this by creating shortcuts in VBA :

```
'Make sure those values fit your version of Excel (these are valid for Excel 2010 up to current version)
Private Const C_MAX_ROWS As Long = 1048576
Private Const C_MAX_COLUMNS As Long = 16384

Sub ActivateCounterScrollLock()
    Application.OnKey "{DOWN}", "MoveDown"
    Application.OnKey "{UP}", "MoveUp"
    Application.OnKey "{LEFT}", "MoveLeft"
    Application.OnKey "{RIGHT}", "MoveRight"
End Sub

Sub DeactivateCounterScrollLock()
    Application.OnKey "{DOWN}"
    Application.OnKey "{UP}"
    Application.OnKey "{LEFT}"
    Application.OnKey "{RIGHT}"
End Sub

Sub MoveDown()
    If TypeName(Selection) = "Range" Then
        If ActiveCell.Row < C_MAX_ROWS Then
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Sub MoveUp()
    If TypeName(Selection) = "Range" Then
        If ActiveCell.Row > 1 Then
            ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Select
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Sub MoveLeft()
    If TypeName(Selection) = "Range" Then
        If ActiveCell.Column > 1 Then
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Select
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Sub MoveRight()
    If TypeName(Selection) = "Range" Then
        If ActiveCell.Column < C_MAX_COLUMNS Then
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

You then run `ActivateCounterScrollLock` when you need those shortcuts to be active and `DeactivateCounterScrollLock` when you're done.

---

### Regarding hidden cells

Although the code above is a proof of concept (ie. it won't replicate exactly the behavior of pressing the arrow keys in Excel while scroll lock is disabled in all cases and it currently doesn't address the issue with Shift+Arrow or Ctrl+Arrow for instance), it would be nice (as mentionned in the comments) if we could end up on a visible cell at least.

At this point, the code will start to get a little more complicated so using the [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), here's one way to change the code above to solve the invisible cells issue:

1 - Add this enum at the top of the module

```
Public Enum Direction
    vbUp = 1
    vbRight = 2
    vbDown = 3
    vbLeft = 4
End Enum
```

2 - Replace the functions above by this:

```
Sub MoveDown()
    MoveSelection vbDown
End Sub

Sub MoveUp()
    MoveSelection vbUp
End Sub

Sub MoveLeft()
    MoveSelection vbLeft
End Sub

Sub MoveRight()
    MoveSelection vbRight
End Sub

Sub MoveSelection(MyDirection As Direction)
    'Do nothing if the selction is not a range
    If TypeName(Selection) = "Range" Then
        Dim Target As Range
        'Make sure that we are not at the edge of the spreasheet
        If IsNotAtLimit(ActiveCell, MyDirection) Then
        
            Set Target = OffsetDirection(ActiveCell, MyDirection)
            'Until we find a non-hidden cell, move in the same direction
            Do While (EntireColOrRow(Target, MyDirection).Hidden = True And IsNotAtLimit(Target, MyDirection))
                Set Target = OffsetDirection(Target, MyDirection)
            Loop
            
            'If all the cells in that directions are hidden, we revert to the Activecell
            If EntireColOrRow(Target, MyDirection).Hidden = True Then
                Set Target = ActiveCell
            End If
            
            Target.Select
            
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

3 - Add the helper functions somewhere in the module:

```
Function OffsetDirection(MyRange As Range, MyDirection As Direction) As Range
    Select Case MyDirection
    Case Is = vbUp
        Set OffsetDirection = MyRange.Offset(-1, 0)
    Case Is = vbRight
        Set OffsetDirection = MyRange.Offset(0, 1)
    Case Is = vbDown
        Set OffsetDirection = MyRange.Offset(1, 0)
    Case Is = vbLeft
        Set OffsetDirection = MyRange.Offset(0, -1)
    End Select
End Function

Function EntireColOrRow(MyRange As Range, MyDirection As Direction) As Variant
    Select Case MyDirection
    Case Is = vbUp
        Set EntireColOrRow = MyRange.EntireRow
    Case Is = vbRight
        Set EntireColOrRow = MyRange.EntireColumn
    Case Is = vbDown
        Set EntireColOrRow = MyRange.EntireRow
    Case Is = vbLeft
        Set EntireColOrRow = MyRange.EntireColumn
    End Select
End Function

Function IsNotAtLimit(MyRange As Range, MyDirection As Direction) As Boolean
    Select Case MyDirection
    Case Is = vbUp
        IsNotAtLimit = (MyRange.Row > 1)
    Case Is = vbRight
        IsNotAtLimit = (MyRange.Column < C_MAX_COLUMNS)
    Case Is = vbDown
        IsNotAtLimit = (MyRange.Row < C_MAX_ROWS)
    Case Is = vbLeft
        IsNotAtLimit = (MyRange.Column > 1)
    End Select
End Function
```

Comment: thanks reply from you but there is an error, I attach a screenshot of the error

Comment: @Jack This is probably because you were in the first column and tried to go left. I've edited the answer to add a check to care of that edge case, but keep in mind that this answer is mostly a proof of concept at the moment and will certainly require some tweaking.

Comment: thanks for the reply from you. If I use the code from for the table and then I filter then the process still follows the whole row even though the row does not appear

Comment: @Jack I've added a new section to my answer to discuss this. Hopefully this helps. However, I hope that you realize that replicating Excel behaviors (with Scroll Lock disabled) exhaustively would probably take at least 3 times the amount of code that I've provided in this answer and this would start to go beyond the reasonable scope of a question on Stack Overflow in my opinion.

Comment: thank you very much. It went so perfectly. You are indeed the best teacher to me